# Parameter as actual code substitution in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to pass a parameter to a function that is used as an actual piece of code

```
this.illuminateLeg = function(whom) {
    var propertiesToIlluminate = [], prop, illuminateInternal, i = 0, delay = 100, intervalId;
    for (key in this.whom.zoom) {
        propertiesToIlluminate.push(this.whom.zoom[key]);
    }
}
```

I am trying to pass a `whom` parameter that is used to iterate over `whom` properties of my object.

I know its possible to pass strings as arguments, but how about actual pieces of code?

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Your question is really unclear. Are you trying to access property of `this`, but you want to get property name from `whom` argument? Then use square bracket syntax, as suggested in answer below. Or you want to pass function ("piece of code") as argument? Then just pass it.

Comment: Got it, the answer below hits the spot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
 for (key in this[whom].zoom)
```

Instead of

```
for (key in this.whom.zoom)
```

and then call the function like this

```
this.illuminateLeg("whom")
```

Answer (score 1):

If the value of `whom` is the name of a property, you can do this:

```
for (key in this[whom].zoom) {
```

Otherwise, you could allow callers to pass in a function which takes the object:

```
this.illuminateLeg = function(getWhom) {
    /* ... */

    for (key in getWhom(this).zoom) {
        /* ... */
    }

// Call with function as argument:
obj.illuminateLeg(function (param) {
    return param.somebody.somethingElse;
});
```